# Understanding ATT Assembly (immediate)

Tags: assembly, x86, att, immediate-operand

lets say i have the following assembly lines

```
movl   $-1, %edi
movl   $1, %edx
```

What exactly am I storing into %edi/%edx registers.

Basically if I were to convert this code into a C program, would I be initalizing some variables to -1 and 1 because that's how I see it and that's where I think I'm getting confused.

I understand that immediate = "some constant" but what does that mean?

Comment: Looks like you already understand it correctly. Immediate is a constant embedded into code. Here we have two constants, -1 and 1.

Comment: Note that this is not the same, necessarily, as initializing a variable in `C`. You are actually loading a value into a register.

Comment: An immediate is a constant, like you say. It's called an immediate because it's encoded into the actual instruction (rather than being from memory).

Comment: AT&T style syntax does everything arseways. You're better off with Intel's syntax. The fewer the number of people who understand AT&T syntax the sooner it dies.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to stick with what my school is teaching me :(

Comment: @James can't agree more. This AT&T syntax is literally a definition of a**-backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four ways to load something into a register:

1. Immediate value - in AT&T assembler, that's using a `$number`, and it loads that particular value (number) into the register. Note that `number` doesn't have to be a numeric value, it could be, for example, `movl $printf, %eax` - this would load the address of the function `printf` into register `eax`.
2. From another register, `movl %eax, %edx` - we now have `eax` value copied into `edx`.
3. From a fixed memory location,   `movl  myvar, %eax` - the contents of `myvar` is in `eax`.
4. From a memory location in another register, `movl (%eax), %edx` - now, `edx` has whatever 32-bit value is at the address in `eax`. Of course, assuming it's actually a "good" memory location - if not, we have a segfault.

If this was C code, the code may loook a bit like this:

1)

```
int x = 42; 

int (*printfunc)(const char *fmt, ...) = printf;
```

2)

```
int x = 1;  
int y = 2; 
..., 
x = y;     // movl  %eax, %edx
```

3)

```
int x = myvar;
```

4)

```
int x = *myptr;
```

Edit: 
Almost everything that is a "source" for a move instruction can also be a source for arithmetic operations, such as `add $3, %eax` will be the equivalent in C of `x += 3;`.

Comment: Just that the inmediate value can also be used in other contexts, e.g., in an addition or other operation.

Comment: You can also use `lea` to load an immediate value or a value from another register (both need to be represeted as a memory address) into a register: 1) `lea eax,number` 2) `lea edx,[eax]` 3) & 4) can't do those with `lea`.